# Moment.js: How to get general semantic expression of time given a number of days

Tags: javascript, time, momentjs

Let's say I have a field that contains, say, a gestation period in terms of a number of days:

```
var gestation = 132; // days
```

Now, let's say, using Moment.js I want to return a value that figures out a semantic expression for that gestation period, depending upon its length. In other words, if the gestation period, is say, 10 days, I want the method to return a value of `about a week` or `10 days` or something similar. If the gestation period is 365 days, I want the method to return a value of `a year` and so on.

How does one write the Moment.js expression to accomplish this?

[This seems similar to the *Time to X* approach described here in the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/to/). But not exactly.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried and achieved so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `humanize()` method.

```
moment.duration(gestation, 'days').humanize();
```

[Found in the documentation here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/).

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `subtract()` combined with `to()` like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omfjh3rx/)